# acess each row before rendering django tables2

Tags: django, django-tables2

I am using djangotables2 to simply render my table but I want to check some condition on each row of a column and print some addition to that value
but I can not find anyway to do so
Is it posible in djangotables2?
view

```
class BowlerList(LoginRequiredMixin, PagedFilteredTableView):
    model = Bowlers
    template_name = 'bowlers_list.html'
    table_class = BowlerTable
    filter_class = BowlerListFilter
    formhelper_class = BowlerListFormHelper

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BowlerList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['select_list'] = UserSelect.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
        return context
```

## table

```
class BowlerTable(dt2.Table):
    name = tables.LinkColumn('bowler-detail', args=[A('pk')])

    class Meta:
        model = Bowlers
        fields = ('name', 'ahprank', 'pcarank')
        template_name = 'django_tables2/bootstrap-responsive.html'
        attrs = {'class': 'table table-striped table-bordered table-hover'}
        per_page = 10
```

template

```
{% render_table table %}
```

i need to compare Name column values with the value I will be getting in my "select_list" which I am getting through the views as context data

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation you can customize the way each cell is rendered. Check it here: https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/custom-data.html#table-render-foo-methods

basically you would add the `render_<column_name>` method and do your stuff there. Like this:

```
class BowlerTable(dt2.Table):
    name = tables.LinkColumn('bowler-detail', args=[A('pk')])

    class Meta:
        model = Bowlers
        fields = ('name', 'ahprank', 'pcarank')
        template_name = 'django_tables2/bootstrap-responsive.html'
        attrs = {'class': 'table table-striped table-bordered table-hover'}
        per_page = 10

    def render_name(self, record):
        # Your code here
```

The only thing extra that you might need, is to pass the `select_list` in the initialization (`__init__`) of the table object, to be able to access it in the new method.

Answer (score 0):

You should check Table.before_render()

```
    A way to hook into the moment just before rendering the template.

    Can be used to hide a column.

    Arguments:
        request: contains the `WGSIRequest` instance, containing a `user` attribute if
            `.django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware` is added to
            your `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`.

    Example::

        class Table(tables.Table):
            name = tables.Column(orderable=False)
            country = tables.Column(orderable=False)

            def before_render(self, request):
                if request.user.has_perm('foo.delete_bar'):
                    self.columns.hide('country')
                else:
                    self.columns.show('country')
```